# Ngnix can't write socket file due to SELinux

Tags: nginx, selinux

When setting up nginx with a socket on my newer environment that runs SELinux I am getting the following error:

```
AVC avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=23704 comm="nginx" name="xxx.sock" dev="nvme0n1p1" ino=17219797 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
```

I googled and searched and found multiple things that should solve this, mainly the following should solve this if I understand correctly:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /opt/run/xxx.sock
restorecon -v /opt/run/xxx.sock
```

But this still doesn't work and I get the same error. I can't find any further solutions and tried with audit2allow which shows the following:

```
allow httpd_t httpd_sys_content_t:sock_file write;
```

But when trying to create a module the whole system kind of freezes (and as I need to do this every deploy this is not an option as it is just a too big of a rocket to shoot at this problem :D )

EDIT:
When turning of selinux (setenforce 0) it works, so this is an SELinux issue

Using nginx version: 1.24.0 on Amazon Linux 2023 running it from a systemd service using a socket file (which has the issue).

Debugging further is see that I get two different errors depending on what I set.
If I set
`semanage fcontext -m -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /opt/run/xxx.sock`
I get a { connectto } error in audit.log (same if I do it with the regex (/.*)? after /run

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1700228218.821:1725): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=15047 comm="nginx" path="/opt/run/xxx.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

Also tried it with httpd_var_run_t, gives the same result

Comment: Is this using the repo version of nginx? What distro?

Comment: I'll edit my question to reflect answers to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the answers and the help! Eventually I did not get it to work with the current sockets setup, but I got it to work thanks to another post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857223/how-do-i-run-flasknginxuwsgi-with-selinux-in-enforcing-mode

The answer in this post shows setting up not with sockets but with HTTP and that works nicely. Just had to set:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1 -P
```

Answer (score 2):

For creating /opt/run/xxx.sock file run the following command in a row.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t var_run_t -s system_u '/opt/(/.*)?'

restorecon -vF /opt

cd /var

ln -s ../opt opt

semanage fcontext -a -t var_run_t -s system_u opt
```

Then restart nginx service, This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command.

```
chcon -t httpd_var_run_t xxx.sock
```

If doesn't work, share the output of `ls -Z xxx.sock` with us.

Comment: chcon has no output, ls-Z of xxx.sock:
system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0

Comment: Wait ls -Z is of course now different than before is used to be httpd_sys_rw_content_t before I did chcon (chcon is I guess a quick way to do semanage -a?)
Also it still doesn't work with the error message:

    type=AVC msg=audit(1700222480.089:6206): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=98135 comm="nginx" path="/var/sockets/xxx.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0

(I changed the location of the sock file)

Comment: Audit2allow now shows the following:

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t initrc_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;

Comment: checkout this will resolve your problem. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349852/selinux-prevents-httpd-write-files.

Comment: No so when I do that I am getting the { connectto } errors (I edited my question to show that more clearly)

Comment: Try this location for your xxx.sock file /var/run/nginx/xxx.conf.

Comment: Sadly still getting error and when giving httpd_t context eventually this:
type=AVC msg=audit(1700561647.801:1928): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=28785 comm="nginx" path="/run/nginx/fir.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0

Comment: disable the selinux once then restart the nginx service and after start selinux .

use setenforce 0 to disable and setenforce 1 to enable the selinux.

Also one more thing did you try this answer:-

For creating /opt/run/xxx.sock file run the following command in a row.

1. semanage fcontext -a -t var_run_t -s system_u '/opt/(/.*)?'

2. restorecon -vF /opt

3. cd /var

4. ln -s ../opt opt

5. semanage fcontext -a -t var_run_t -s system_u opt

Then restart nginx service, This should resolve your issue.

Comment: OK, tried both things, still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Check File Permissions:

Confirm that the file permissions on the socket file allow the Nginx process to write to it.

```
chmod +w xxx.sock
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't have anything to do with file permissions but with SELinux. I'll edit my question to make that more clear